# PHP: Making a simple screen transition Dashboard

Tags: php

im planning to make a Simple Screen transition Dashboard. I am going to make several stored procedures that returns columns to be displayed between transitions.

My question is what would be the best way to do this in PHP, since this is the only accessible language to be used with MSSQL and that doesnt need license.

I was thinking to make a hidden Pane(Frame) that handles the delay and loop that loads the Main Page. But im worried that between transition it will take time to Load and might not be a good presentation.

Any tips?

Sorry.. Simple Screen Transition..
Ex. First page, shows columns (customer, number of transactions, total sales)
Second Page, Pie Chart of Last Month vs This Month
Third Page, shows columns (seller, number of transactions, total costs )
Fourth Page, shows the Bargraph of Costs for this years months vs last years months
and so on.. like 10 of like this.

I was adviced on making like an advertisement of sort. Like an Infinite Loop of Power Point presentation that does real time query as the Data is updated every minute.

Hope I did some clarifications, if it didnt please let me know.

FYI. The client PC that will handle this will only have the local webserver ( i will use xampp) and will connect to MSSQL thru network, they wont have access to the internet for security reasons that I dont know.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more what exactly a "Simple Screen transition Dashboard" is or does?

Comment: I suggest you look at jQuery/Ajax to load the (php) content that you want in the 'hidden Pane(Frame)'. Futher, i have no idea what you are trying to accomplice.

Comment: question edited. thanks for the interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your php print them as normal html (nothing special there).
For your panels, have a page with div containers and use AJAX to load your php intermittently (JQuery and JQuery UI would be the easiest. Make a JavaScript function that uses JQuery delay() and then calls itself to set up a timer that loads the pages into the div containers using $.ajax()

Comment: this seems nice. i might post more questions regarding AJAX. just need to study AJAX first. Thank you for the answer. Any reason why I should use AJAX instead? or are there any more basic ways to do it?

Comment: This is the best way to do "real time" php, since php is stateless (it won't run continously, watching for updates to your database). Technically, neither does JavaScript, but you can set up a $.delay() function that calls an $.ajax() function and itself in an infinite loop, every specified number of milliseconds. The ajax function would run your php script and put the result into one of your div containers. This sounds hackish, but this is the most widely accepted way to simulate 'real time php'.

Comment: thank you. Never had the courage to use AJAX before. but thank you!